# Keep aspect 4:3 ratio & scale video div on a chat app using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am playing around with WebRTC and I want to create a video chat. I am after a layout that looks something like this:

[image]

Using best of my knowledge, I've put together the following:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-commenting" aria-hidden="true"></i> My Chat App</a> 
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#navbar-main" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Help</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> 1 Online</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-ld-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body pad5">
                    <div style="height: 320px; background-color: #000;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    Them
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body pad5">
                    <div style="height: 320px; background-color: #000;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    You
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-ld-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p><b>You</b>: Hello</p>
                    <p><b>Them</b>: Hi</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer custom-panel-footer pad5">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="message-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-commenting" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message here ..." aria-describedby="message-icon">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i> Send
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This does not render quite right, here's a preview:

[image]

How can I implement the layout like my sketch? I just want "My" and "Their" video div to keep the 4:3 aspect ratio and scale with available width.

When the window resizes, I want the whole layout to shrink whilst keeping the aspect ratio of the video divs. But on a larger monitor, if there's space, i want the video divs to scale up whilst maintaining the aspect ratio.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may use the thumbnail for this as well from Bootstrap. And for the update, you need `@media` query for larger devices to make it look bigger. Lemme know if the dupe doesn't answer your question, I'll reopen it and answer it too.

Comment: Hi. The dupe doesn't make sense. Can you re open it please?

Comment: Reopened the question.